# HelloGoogleMaps - Not Downloading Map Data

Tags: android, maps

I can't get the HelloGoogleMaps tutorial (or my implementation in another project either) to download maps when its ran. It works fine in Google's Maps application, but not in the project. What is going on!

**Map**

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    addLocation(1,19.240000, -99.120000, "Hhola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
    addLocation(2,35.410000, -139.460000, "Sekai, konichiwa!", "I'm in Japan!");

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

public void addLocation(int index, double latitude, double longitude, String textPrimary, String textSecondary){

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redmarker_a);
    if(index == 2)
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redmarker_b);
    else if(index == 3)
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.palebluemarker_u);

    ItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(drawable,getApplicationContext());

    GeoPoint newPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1000000),(int)(longitude * 1000000));
    OverlayItem newOverlayItem = new OverlayItem(newPoint, textPrimary, textSecondary);

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(newOverlayItem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);       
}
}
```

**ItemizedOverlay:**

```
public class ItemizedOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
Context mContext;

public ItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
  return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
  return mOverlays.size();
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.apl.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".Map"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="09e81PCxJyJXAblqt5veOmOE7Yy4-X6P5nLKi3Q"
/>
```

**This code works if I go to a 2.3.3 project in the emulator. But not a 3.0.1 on my device.**

Comment: I took your code and put it into my mapping app, works fine, works fine on emulator 2.1,2.2,2.3.3,3.0,3.1 also on devices 2.2,2.3,3.1 I don't have a 3.0 piece of hardware.   I do get a forced close if I tap on one of your markers but all the tiles show up fine.

Answer (score 0):

also make sure ur putting uses permission for internet in your manifest and if your testing on the emulator u need to enable internet with the -dns 8.8.8.8 startup argument

sorry i do see that u have the permissions for internet but make sure u can access the web if your using the emulator

also take note that the mapapi key is tied to your "signing" file (the export step, if your testing on a real device) meaning if u used test.keystore to make your maps api key then created a new keystore you would have to redo the maps api key

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ported the app back to 2.3.3 and it works on the emulator. Still same issues on my 3.0 device.

Comment: id be willing to bet the tutorial was written for 2.  which if u think about it is better for you, because more ppl have 2 then 3 and you want to reach the largest market for your app.  all of my apps are written in 2.x

Comment: I'm not trying to release the app though, it is imperative I get it working on 3.0 ASAP. Do you have any ideas on how to change the code?

Comment: i have multiple emulators for each version, idk if you do, but u did confirm that u can access the internet on the 3.0 emulated device right?  ill search around and see what i can find.

Comment: Yes I have internet on it. Thanks!